# Image difference in Java

Tags: java, performance, optimization, bufferedimage, difference

```
public float calculateDifference(BufferedImage b1, BufferedImage b2){
    float error = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
            Color c1 = new Color(b1.getRGB(x, y));
            Color c2 = new Color(b2.getRGB(x, y));
            error += Math.abs(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed());
            error += Math.abs(c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen());
            error += Math.abs(c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue());
            error += Math.abs(c1.getAlpha() - c2.getAlpha());
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

I have this function that compares two bufferedimages. It returns a higher error if the two images are more different. The only problem is it runs really slowly so is there any more efficient way to do this? Any way to lower the runtime would really help.

Comment: how big is sizeY and sizeX, and how slow is slow?

Comment: sizeX and sizeY are initialized somewhere else in the code. They are the sizes of both bufferedimages. By slow I mean longer than I would like and any speed increase would be great since my program uses this code atleast once per update.

Comment: Working with bufimage.getData() may be faster. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292418/manipulating-the-pixels-within-a-bufferedimage-through-an-array

Comment: Sure, working with an image pixelwise is always damn slow. Grab the image data and enjoy the speed up. Or try [ImageOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html).

Comment: how long does it take and how fast you need it be? You want portable code or only for your system?

Comment: I only need it to work for windows and also the error number does not need to be the same as it is right now. If there is a better way to determine the error as long as I get higher error for more difference that will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can optimize the internal for loop.
Don't create new Color objects. Use directly the int value of RGB. This will limit the number of Objects created and the frequency of call to Garbage collection.

```
int color1 = b1.getRGB(x, y);
int alpha1 = (color1 >> 24) & 0xFF;
int red1 = (color1 >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green1 = (color1 >> 8) & 0xFF; 
int blue1 = (color1 >> 0) & 0xFF;

int color2 = b2.getRGB(x, y);
int alpha2 = (color2 >> 24) & 0xFF;
int red2 = (color2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green2 = (color2 >> 8) & 0xFF; 
int blue2 = (color2 >> 0) & 0xFF;

error += Math.abs(red1 - red2);
error += Math.abs(green1 - green2);
error += Math.abs(blue1 - blue2);
error += Math.abs(alpha1 - alpha2);
```